# java game I have made won't keep score

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Game{
    int score = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name; 
    String enter;
    public void Play() {
        System.out.print("Enter Player One Name: ");
        name = reader.nextLine();//enter player name
```

Only using one player for now waiting to see if it works with one before adding another

```
            System.out.println("Welcome Players!"+
                "To win the game press enter to roll" +
                "The first player to score 50 wins!!!"+
                "Press enter to start the game!!!");
            enter = reader.nextLine(); //This is a dummy code. Just pauses and waits for enter press.
            int roll = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);        
            score += roll;  //will add roll value to current score
            System.out.println("you rolled a: " + roll + " and are now on " 
                + score);
            while(score <= 50){
                //String enter;
                enter = reader.nextLine();
                roll = (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);
                score += roll;
```

I had thought that this would add the number you rolled to your current score.

```
        if(roll % 7==0){
            System.out.println("move forward 2 spaces!!" +
                "New score is: " + score );
        }else{
            System.out.println(score);
        }

        if(roll % 9==0){
            System.out.println("Sorry move back two spaces :("+
                "New score is: " + score);
        }else{
            System.out.println(score);
        }

        if (roll == 12){
            System.out.println("oh no! You lost all points"+
                "New score is: " + score + roll);
            score = 0;
        }else{
            System.out.println(score );
        }
        System.out.println(roll);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make this readable? You know that the indentation is correct, and that the code doesn't stop half way a method? Also there is no `main` method. Welcome to stackoverflow.com you already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860321/why-wont-my-game-keep-score-it-should-take-the-number-you-rolled-and-add-it-to), improve the question instead asking the very same thing.

Comment: I'm sorry I really have zero clue what  I'm doing. I can't figure out how to make this work and its for my high school midterm tomorrow. I have zero clue on coding or anything computer related my school put me in the class when I am neither qualified or competent enough for this and I can't transfer into something else. I'm really very sorry I'll try to fix it but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Are you ever creating new *instances* of `Game`?

Answer (score 0):

`roll` will always be between one and six, according to this code, and thus none of the `if` tests will ever be true. Did you mean to test `score`, perhaps? Or maybe you meant to accumulate rolls in `roll` by doing `roll += (int)(Math.random()* 6 + 1);` in your loop?

Comment: This is a request for clarification, not an answer; it should be a comment.

Comment: At least he going in the right direction, poor questions can get poor answers. The OP just dumps code, how would you answer this question? Or you wouldn't even try?